# Css animation - with vertical line on a horizontal line

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have an expanding line animation in css as can be seen in the [demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-8l6bh1?file=/index.html)

I would like some help in figuring out how to add a vertical line at both ends when the animation stops.

Something like the attached image :
[image]

Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using pseudo elements

```
.line::before,
.line::after
{
  content: ''; /* important for pseudo elements */
  width: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
.line::after { right: 0 } /* snap to right */
.line::before { left: 0 } /* snap to left */
```